# Specify provider for next-auth/react using Auth0

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, auth0, next-auth

I have a NextJS application which uses Auth0 for authentication. I have two Auth0 tenants which I want to use for two separate register and login functionalities. I understand I can create Roles in one and only work with one, but this is not an option. I have added two Auth0 providers in my [...nextauth].ts file as shown below. Basically, what I want is to have two login buttons, one which has an Auth0 provider for Auth0 tenant 1, and one which has an Auth0 provider for Auth0 tenant 2. I am using next-auth/react for signIn("auth0"), and I want to be able to specify which Auth0 provider should be used to handle this. Here is the code I have:

[...nextauth].ts:

```
import NextAuth, { type NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import Auth0Provider from 'next-auth/providers/auth0'

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  secret: process.env.AUTH0_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login'
  },
  providers: [
    Auth0Provider({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
      idToken: true,
      issuer: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL
    }),
    Auth0Provider({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH0_TENANT_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_TENANT_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
      idToken: true,
      issuer: process.env.AUTH0_TENANT_ISSUER_BASE_URL
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    signIn({ profile }) {
      return !!profile
    },
    redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return url.startsWith(baseUrl) ? `${baseUrl}/` : baseUrl
    },
    jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token
      }
      return token
    },
    session({ session, token }) {
      return { ...session, ...token }
    }
  }
}
export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

Here is my code for my login button:

```
// material-ui
import { Button, Grid, Typography } from '@mui/material'

// assets
import LockIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Lock'

// func
import { useLanguage } from '@/hooks/i18n/useLanguage'
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react'

const LoginBtn = () => {
  const { t } = useLanguage()

  return (
    <Grid
      container
      spacing={0}
      direction="column"
      alignItems="center"
      justifyContent="center"
      className="h-screen">
      <Button
        className="h-20 w-72 rounded-full bg-arealizeGreenDark text-arealizeBeigeLight hover:bg-arealizeGreenLight"
        onClick={() => {
          void signIn('auth0')
        }}>
        <Typography>{t.general.login_btn}</Typography>
        <LockIcon className="ml-2" />
      </Button>
    </Grid>
  )
}

export default LoginBtn
```

As you can see, I have two Auth0Providers implemented in the [...nextauth].ts file. With this, when I click the signin button, it always chooses the top provider. I want a way to specify which provider should be used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify an unique `id` for each provider:

```js
[
  Auth0Provider({
    id:"first", // <-- add this line
    clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID as string,
    clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    idToken: true,
    issuer: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL,
  }),
  Auth0Provider({
    id:"second", // <-- add this line
    clientId: process.env.AUTH0_TENANT_CLIENT_ID as string,
    clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_TENANT_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    idToken: true,
    issuer: process.env.AUTH0_TENANT_ISSUER_BASE_URL,
  }),
];
```

Then call the `signIn()` method with the id of the provider you want to sign in with :

```js
signIn('first')
//or
signIn('second')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this did not work. It gives me an error. When logging the Auth0Provider object, the id is still auth0, and it's only the provider.options.id that is set to "first". However, even if I use signIn("first"), it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was facing something similar and finally figured it out... I had to look here at the docs for next-auth to determine what the Auth0Provider actually returned (https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/v4/packages/next-auth/src/providers/auth0.ts)

Then, looking at what the next-auth docs pointed me to I for CUSTOM OAUTH setup I took the fields returned from the Auth0 Provider Code and came up with a provider object that looked like:

```
{
     id: 'first',
     name: 'Auth0',
     wellKnown: `${env.oauth.baseUrl}/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
     type: 'oauth',
     checks: ['pkce', 'state'],
     idToken: true,
     profile(profile) {
       return {
         id: profile.sub,
         name: profile.nickname,
         email: profile.email,
         image: profile.picture,
       };
     },
     clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
     clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
     issuer: process.env.OAUTH_URL,

     token: {
       params: {
         // Add any other token endpoint params here
         scope: 'openid email profile',
       },
     },

     authorization: {
       params: {
         // Add any other authorization endpoint params here
         scope: 'openid email profile',
         connection: FOR MY SAKE I USED DIFFERENT DB CONNECTIONS,
       },
     },
   }
```

Finally, for the providers array I supplied:

```
providers = [{
      id: 'first',
      name: 'Auth0',
      wellKnown: `${env.oauth.baseUrl}/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
      type: 'oauth',
      checks: ['pkce', 'state'],
      idToken: true,
      profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.nickname,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.picture,
        };
      },
      clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.OAUTH_URL,

      token: {
        params: {
          // Add any other token endpoint params here
          scope: 'openid email profile',
        },
      },

      authorization: {
        params: {
          // Add any other authorization endpoint params here
          scope: 'openid email profile',
          connection: FOR MY SAKE I USED DIFFERENT DB CONNECTIONS,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      id: 'second',
      name: 'Auth0',
      wellKnown: `${env.oauth.baseUrl}/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
      type: 'oauth',
      checks: ['pkce', 'state'],
      idToken: true,
      profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.nickname,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.picture,
        };
      },
      clientId: process.env.AUTH0_OTHER_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_OTHER_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.OAUTH_URL,

      token: {
        params: {
          // Add any other token endpoint params here
          scope: 'openid email profile',
        },
      },

      authorization: {
        params: {
          // Add any other authorization endpoint params here
          scope: 'openid email profile',
          connection: FOR MY SAKE I USED DIFFERENT DB CONNECTIONS,
        },
      },
    },
],
```

Then, since so much of the config is the same I refactored to a function that took the parameters of the fields I needed to change and returned the config object that was required.

Hope this helps! Happy Hacking!